# DC/OS on Azure: Automatically mount disk

Tags: azure, terraform, mesos, dcos, terraform-provider-azure

I just installed a DC/OS Cluster on Azure using Terraform. Now I was wondering if it's possible to automatically mount Data Disks of agent nodes under `/dcos/volume<N>`. As far as I understood the docs, this is a manual task. Wouldn't it be possible to automate this step with Terraform? I was looking through the DC/OS docs and Terraform docs but I couldn't find anything related to auto mounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just can mount the Data disks to the node of AKS manual as a volume. It's a Kubernetes task, not Azure's. Azure only can manage the data disk for you.

What you can do through the Terraform is attach the data disk to the node itself of AKS as a disk, not a volume of the AKS. And the volume, you only can create it through Kubernetes, not Azure. So Terraform also cannot help you achieve it automated.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I'm not sure what this has to do with Kubernetes. AFAIK Terraform sets up Resources on Azure using Azure Resource Manager and also installs and configures DC/OS on those VMs. So I'd say Terraform can execute remote tasks. Therefore I assumed it must be possible to also mount a Disk using Terraform. But maybe I miss up things here...

Comment: @Roman Yes, as I say in the answer, you can mount the disks to AKS nodes as the disks. But you cannot set them as the volume for AKS through Terraform.